# Download Lone Image From a Set of URLs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a set of URLs and names in a file as follows:

```
www.test.yom/something/somethingelse/Profile.aspx?id=1
John Doe
www.test.yom/something/somethingelse/Profile.aspx?id=24
John Benjamin
www.test.yom/something/somethingelse/Profile.aspx?id=307
Benjamin Franklin
....
```

Each URL page contains normal html and any amount of text, tables, etc. but will always have 1 image in an  tag.

My goal is to download this image somehow to my drive, renaming it with the second line name (i.e. "John Doe.jpg" and "John Benjamin.jpg").

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I parsed out the URL-Name file from raw HTML on a different page using UNIX commands (grep, tr, sed), but I'm guessing this will require something a bit more intricate. Right now I'm thinking Python script, but I'm not exactly sure which libraries to look at or where to start in general (although I am familiar with Python language itself). I would also be down to use Java or any other language if it would make the process easier. Any advice?

Edit: So... ran into a problem where the urls require authentication to access. This is fine but the problem is that it is two-step authentication, and the second step is a passcode sent to mobile. :-( But thanks for the help!

Comment: Definitely take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing the image tag. It'll also make the job of fetching the URL/Name data from your starting HTML - no more UNIX commands required!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the links in a list or a file and use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get the html, then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) to find the image you want, extract the `src` attribute and use requests again to download the file. Both libraries are quite simple to use, you won't have a problem doing that simple script :).

Pseudo-code to help you start:

```
url_list = ['url1', 'url2']
for url in url_list:
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    img_element = soup.find('img')
    image_url = img_element['src']
    requests.download(image_url) # Not sure how to download this to a file
```

Comment: Sweet. This is exactly what I was looking for I think. Since the image is guaranteed to be the only img tag, would BeautifulSoup be easier than using a regex? I guess coming up with the regex would take more effort than just importing the library...

Comment: A lot easier and a lot more reliable, trust me, BeautifulSoup looks intimidating but it's really simple to use, take a look at the pseudo code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [extraction](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/extraction/) module with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module :

```
pip install requests
pip install extraction
```

Then:

```
import extraction
import requests

url = "http://google.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text

extracted = extraction.Extractor().extract(html, source_url=url)

print(extracted.image) # If you know that there is only one image in your page
print(extracted.images) # List of images on page

http://google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png
['http://google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png']
```

Note that `source_url` is optional in extract, but is recommendedas it makes it possible to rewrite relative urls and image urls into absolute paths.

And  `extracted.image` is first item of `extracted.images` if exist, or `None`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to bypass the two-step authentication. Note that for the URLs I had if I log into one of the URLs and click the "Remember Me" option on login, this avoids the login page for the following method.

1. Download the "Save images" extension on Firefox. Restart Firefox.
2. In Tools -> "Save images" -> Options. Go to "Save" tab. In "Folder Options", pick folder to save files. In "File Names", pick "Use file name:". Enter appropriate file name.
3. Go to "http://tejji.com/ip/open-multiple-urls.aspx" in Firefox (not Chrome).
4. Copy and paste only the URLs into the textbox. Click "Submit". After all tabs load, close the tejji.com tab.
5. On the first profile page, right click -> "Save images" -> "Save images from ALL tabs".
6. Close the Save prompt if everything looks right.
7. All the images should now be in your designated folder.

All that's left is to rename the files based on the names (the files are numbered in order which coincide with order of names if you kept URLs in same order), but that should be rudimentary.